# Why does adding an id to my svg path break the hover transition?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a custom hoverable shape using a trigger shape, but the hover effect applies in the view box of the SVG instead of the shape itself. To try to fix this I added an id to the path itself, but now the transition does not work at all. What would be the best way to fix this?

```css
body{
    background-color: #ECEDED;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-width: max-content;
    margin: 0;
}
svg{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.hover_infilm{
    position: absolute;
    top:-22px;
    left:60px;
    z-index:1;
}
#path_hover_infilm{
    z-index:1;
}
.a_infilm{
    position: absolute;
    top:-51px;
    left:60px;
    z-index:-8;
    opacity: 0%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#path_hover_infilm:hover + .a_infilm{
    transform: scale(1.15) rotate(4deg);
    opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg class="hover_infilm" width="863" height="545" viewBox="0 0 863 545" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M718.983 0.950684L1.7179 261.834L605.491 543.503L803.515 521.505L861.971 33.4759L718.983 0.950684Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0%" id="path_hover_infilm"/>

</svg>
<svg class="a_infilm" width="863" height="545" viewBox="0 0 863 545" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M718.983 0.950684L1.7179 261.834L605.491 543.503L803.515 521.505L861.971 33.4759L718.983 0.950684Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you trying to transform the path in the second SVG rather than the whole of the second SVG?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #path_hover_infilm:hover + .a_infilm {}
>
> <svg class="hover_infilm" ...>
>   <path id="path_hover_infilm" .../>
> </svg>
> <svg class="a_infilm" ...>
>   <path .../>
> </svg>
> ```

Your selector is wrong. You are using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`) but `path` is a child of `svg` and is not a sibling to the next `svg`.

You will need to use the class or ID that is set on the SVG

```
.hover_infilm:hover + .a_infilm {}
```

> the hover effect applies in the view box of the SVG instead of the shape itself.

I don't know how to help you there, but targeting the hover on `path` instead of `svg` doesn't make a difference. However, you can try this with `.hover_infilm:has(path:hover) + .a_infilm{}`

```css
body{
    background-color: #ECEDED;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-width: max-content;
    margin: 0;
}
svg{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.hover_infilm{
    position: absolute;
    top:-22px;
    left:60px;
    z-index:1;
}
#path_hover_infilm{
    z-index:1;
}
.a_infilm{
    position: absolute;
    top:-51px;
    left:60px;
    z-index:-8;
    opacity: 0%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover_infilm:hover + .a_infilm{
    transform: scale(1.15) rotate(4deg);
    opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg class="hover_infilm" width="863" height="545" viewBox="0 0 863 545" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M718.983 0.950684L1.7179 261.834L605.491 543.503L803.515 521.505L861.971 33.4759L718.983 0.950684Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0%"/>
</svg>
<svg class="a_infilm" width="863" height="545" viewBox="0 0 863 545" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M718.983 0.950684L1.7179 261.834L605.491 543.503L803.515 521.505L861.971 33.4759L718.983 0.950684Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```